# Angular 2 required is not defined

Tags: angular

If I don't want to use CDN cuz I installed NPM packages, do I need to install SystemJS ?

Currently, angular2 Cli does not include SystemJS. so that it is hard to set up for me.

I wanted use Chartjs so I installed NPM packages but not working as below,

```
    npm install chart.js --save

    <script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>
```

Error message : **required is not defined**

This is working if I use CDN as below

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Could you advise for me I am getting panic now.....

Comment: Why do you use src/chart.js and not dist/Chart.js? And why don't you install it as a library in your angular CLI build? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-lib, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib

Comment: @JBNizet omg... working.... that is why??? Thank you so much !!!  one more questions, if I don't know which js file I need to add, what should I do after installed NPM packages? Cuz also, i am looking for auth0 which I use CDN, but I also installed NPM as well, but I don't know which js file do i need to include..... I can't find same name as CDN has.

Comment: chartjs is implemented as an IIFE. You only need to include the script tag to load it.  Angular2 normally would require SystemJS, unless your linking to the @angular2 libraries by including the UMD script bundles directly (I assume you're not), or you're using static bundles (AOT), which I assume you're not either.